# How to run a directive after the dom finished rendering in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm try to render the template dynamiclly, How to run the directive after {{tag}} has been rendered finished ?

directive:

```
angular.module('services', [])
    .directive('demo', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/template.html',
            restrict: 'C'
        }
    });
```

controller:

```
angular.module('controller', [])
    .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.tag = "demo";
        $scope.clickHandler = function() {
            // do something when click button
        }
    }]);
```

view:

```
<button ng-click="clickHandler()">Button</button>
<div class="{{tag}}"></div>
```

Comment: you should pass in the dynamic `tag` into the scope of directive and implement a logic in side the link function, or template using that passed in tag. `<span class="my-dir: tag"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can user in your `directive` following structure:

```
 app.directive('example', function() {

    var directive : {
        link:link,
        restrict:'C',
        templateUrl:'...'
    } 

    function link($scope,$element,$attrs, $rootScope){
      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
         // dom here
      })
    }

    return directive;
}
```

Try it and see if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cosmo wrote its need to be done in **link** function but instead awaiting whole document you can wait only for directive dom ready.
Second argument of link function is **$element** you can use it.

```
app.directive('example', function() {

var directive : {
    link:link,
    restrict:'C',
    templateUrl:'...'
} 

function link($scope, $element, $attrs, $rootScope){
  $element.ready(function() {
     // dom here
  })
}

return directive;
}
```

Comment: using `$` in link function is not necessary because its arguments are not injectable and it causes confusion.